# What is the asymptotic runtime complexity of the UIView convert(_:to:) method?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

What is the asymptotic runtime complexity of the UIView method [convert(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert)?

My best guess is constant time but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Asymptotic as a function of what?

Comment: What makes you think it's linear time? As Martin asked, what would it be linear over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(1)`. It boils down to a trivial some `NSPoint` additions/subtractions.

[`NSView.convertPoint:fromView:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483269-convertpoint?language=objc) is similar, and you can see [an implementation of it by GNUStep](https://github.com/thezerobit/gnustep-gui-sony/blob/master/Source/NSView.m#L1561-L1586):

```
- (NSPoint) convertPoint: (NSPoint)aPoint fromView: (NSView*)aView
{
  NSPoint   new;
  NSAffineTransform *matrix;

  if (!aView)
    aView = [[_window contentView] superview];
  if (aView == self || aView == nil)
    return aPoint;
  NSAssert(_window == [aView window], NSInvalidArgumentException);

  matrix = [aView _matrixToWindow];
  new = [matrix transformPoint: aPoint];

  if (_coordinates_valid)
    {
      matrix = _matrixFromWindow;
    }
  else
    {
      matrix = [self _matrixFromWindow];
    }
  new = [matrix transformPoint: new];

  return new;
}
```